# How can I split a string on integer-comma substrings?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I want to split a string by commas but only with a number before comma. The number must be present in result groups.

It works fine until input string contains a comma without a number before, this comma should be a part of value group.

What should i change in the first regexp?

```js
const doSplit = (parameter_type) => parameter_type.split(/(?!\d+)\,\s/).map((option) => {
      const matches = option.match(/(?<value>.+)\s(?<key>\d+)$/)
      if(matches === null) {
        return {Error: {option, parameter_type}}
       }
      return matches.groups
 })
 
 const list_a = "No reaction 0, Up 1, Down 3, Stop 5, Position 1 6, Position 2 7, Position 3 8, Position 4 9, Individual position 10, Enable automatic sun protection 14"
 
 console.log(doSplit(list_a))
 
 const list_b = "End position, no overflow 0, End position + 2% overflow 2, End position + 5% overflow 5, End position + 10% overflow 10, End position + 20% overflow 20, Total travel time + 10% Overflow 255"
 console.log(doSplit(list_b))
```

Comment: *"this comma should be a part of value group."*: can you give an example of input and expected output where this happens?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: const expected = [
    {
        value: 'End position, no overflow',
        key: 0,
    },
    {
        value: 'End position + 2% overflow',
        key: 2, 
    },
    ...
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with just one regex, and `matchAll`:

```js
const regex = /\s*,?\s*(?<value>.+?)\s+(?<key>\d+)(?=,|$)/g;
const doSplit = (parameter_type) => 
    Array.from(parameter_type.matchAll(regex), ({groups}) => groups);
 
 const list_a = "No reaction 0, Up 1, Down 3, Stop 5, Position 1 6, Position 2 7, Position 3 8, Position 4 9, Individual position 10, Enable automatic sun protection 14"
 console.log(doSplit(list_a))
 
 const list_b = "End position, no overflow 0, End position + 2% overflow 2, End position + 5% overflow 5, End position + 10% overflow 10, End position + 20% overflow 20, Total travel time + 10% Overflow 255"
 console.log(doSplit(list_b))
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like some crazy regex skill. Where did you learn that?

Comment: I wouldn't want to boast about my regex skills... there's still much to learn for me. But I guess it comes from years of experience.